# Existence and uniqueness of a solution for the stationary transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Let $\lambda > 0$, $a$ and $S \in C^1(\mathbb R^n)$. Supose that it exists $M > 0$ such that:

$a(x) \geq 0$ and $|\nabla a(x)| + |S(x)| + |\nabla S(x)| \leq M$, $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Show that the stationary transport equation:

$\lambda f(x) + v\cdot \nabla_x f(x) + a(x)f(x) = S(x)$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$

has a unique limited $C^1(\mathbb R^n)$ solution.

thanks in advance.